# How to make reactions (when editing embed) in discord.py faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

the code works just fine now, but after using it for a while, i found out some bugs around it. My problem is that after the user reacts to embed using reactions (picture shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY67O.png)), from clicking the reaction to actually editing the embed is taking too long (in range of 1-3 seconds), which isn't ideal when too many users reacts at once or one user reacts to more answers in it.

Sometimes when the user reacts too fast, it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8EEj.png). As you can see, I reacted too fast on two answers and "un-reacted" to it. It showed some change in the embed, but at last it showed nothing. The user has to "un-react" it and react to it again to show any change in the embed.

My theory is that my code is just bad and/or the API can't keep up with that. Do you have any suggestions how to make it faster without any tradeoffs?

The code is shown below with comments to show why I'm doing it and why for.

```python
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
   
   #open an json to retrieve the embed ID where I added it
    with open("cogs/message_id.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    
    #fetch the channel and message from the payload id
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

    #don't react to anything other than in json file
    if payload.message_id in data["message_ids"]:

        embed = message.embeds[0]
        reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
        
        #prepared the dictionary for reactions, as it helps with performance
        emoticon_dict = {
            "1️⃣": 0,
            "2️⃣": 1,
            "3️⃣": 2,
            "4️⃣": 3,
            "5️⃣": 4,
            "6️⃣": 5,
            "7️⃣": 6,
            "8️⃣": 7,
            "9️⃣": 8,
            "": 9
        }
        dictionary = {}
        i = emoticon_dict[str(payload.emoji)]
        dictionary[i] = reaction.count - 1 #the bot vote counts, subtract it
        
        #set for when duplicates are in there
        members = set()
        async for user in reaction.users():
            if user.id == self.bot.user.id:  #don't add bot user to it
                continue
            else:
                members.add(user)
        
        #show the votes in members = set() and join them
        vypis_hlasu = f"{', '.join(user.display_name for user in members)}"
        #edit the message based on dictionary index
        edit = embed.set_field_at(i, name=embed.fields[i].name, value="{} | {}".format(dictionary[i], vypis_hlasu),
                                  inline=False)
        await reaction.message.edit(embed=edit)
```

In case if you're wondering about on_raw_reaction_remove decorator, the code is same.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Get a better internet connection?

Comment: I'm not running bot from local network, as I have average internet speed. I'm using a server that is located in Poland, where the network is (can't measure it, but used a command that measures its latency) and it is somewhere in range 60 - 122 ms. Is it worrisome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was kind of simple. I was able to insert those values into MySQL database so I don't use an JSON to add message ids. I created a simple cache that caches the ids from database using pythonic set() for faster searching through extensive values as shown below:

```py
class Poll(commands.Cog):
   def __init__(self, bot):
      self.bot = bot
      self.caching = set()
      self.cache.start()

   @commands.command()
   async def your_command(self, ctx):
     #here you should insert ctx.message.id into the database and self.caching
     pass

   @tasks.loop(minutes=30)
   async def cache(self):
        try:
            self.cursor = self.connect(user="xxx", password="xxx", host="xxx", database="xxx")
            #so you don't overclog your databse.
            query2 = "DELETE FROM `Poll` WHERE `DateOfPoll` < CURRENT_DATE - 7;"
            self.cursor.execute(operation=query2)

            query = "SELECT `PollID` FROM `Poll`"
            tuples = self.query(query = query)
            
            #set comprehension for having clean numbers in cache, return of tuples are [("321654", " "...)]
            self.caching = {int(clean_variable) for variable in tuples for clean_variable in variable}

            return self.caching

        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            print(e)
            self.database.rollback()

        finally:
            self.close(commit=True)
      
    @cache.before_loop
    async def before_cache(self):
        try:
            self.cursor = self.connect(user="xxx", password="xxx", host="xxx", database="xxx")
            query = "your query"
            self.cursor.execute(query)

        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            print(e)
            self.database.rollback()
            return

        finally:
            self.close(commit=True)
```

this allows me to insert those values into database and cache them every 30 minutes. For creating next embeds, I simply add new values into `self.caching` and insert to database. If I was only inserting to database, the reactions won't work as the ID of embed isn't in cache and you would have to wait for 30 minutes to sort it all out. With `self.caching.add(id_embed)` you have instant reactions, as time complexity of Pythonic set is (on average) O(1) as shown [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

There are some bugs here and there, but overall the optimization on average is faster than opening json and reading through a list. Another approach to this problem is using dictionary than set for caching, but I wasn't able to further explore this idea.

You should also take in the API limits. You can't go faster than that, but I was able to reproduce the same code with better results.